# Which dialect of LISP is 'The Little Lisper' [3rd Edn] written in? (at the time)

Tags: lisp, dialect

The Little Lisper is an extraordinary book. 
[http://www.amazon.com/Little-LISPer-Third-Daniel-Friedman/dp/0023397632/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1279715423&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0023397632)

Does anyone know which dialect/version of LISP it was written for at the time of publication?
Perhaps

1. Common LISP
2. Standardised Scheme
3. Some LISP-1 dialect lost in the sands of time predating modern standards from 1989

Does anyone know what the features/attributes of this version/dialect are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about the third edition, but the early ones were Scheme around R4RS.  There is also the slightly newer translation "The Little Schemer'. I'm pretty sure that most of the code should run fine in any modern scheme.  I'd suggest Racket (AKA PLT Scheme) as it is at constructed by a team led by Matthias Felleisen.

Edit:
Looking at the dates, it was in a pre-standardization version of Scheme.